# Measuring resistance in corrosion removal electrolysis

Tags: power-supply, electrolysis

I tried to measure the resistance of my electrolysis setup (rusty object on cathode, clean iron anode, electrolyte = 3l H2O + 1tb spoon baking soda). But the resistance fluctuated from 50 to 70 kΩ even when everything was still. During the reading it would usually climb up. Sometimes I even got a negative reading (when I added more baking soda). Could something about the way the multimeter measures resistance cause this? How can I measure the actual resistance and in what range should I expect it to be?

I want to know because I have a 12 V, max 12 A power supply + (16 A current limiting socket) and I worry that it is just too much power for some of the cables.

Note: The power supply is a 350 W ATX power supply with a selection of voltages from 3.3 V to 12 V.

Comment: I'm not a chemist, but if there is some activation potential which your DMM in resistance mode does not reach over, you will get different results with multimeter versus 12 V applied. How about setting it for current measurement and hook it in series with your power supply?

Comment: Gonna have to buy a better ampmeter then, mine is rated at max 10A.

Comment: You can also cheat with a shunt resistor of suitable value and measure the voltage across it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The electrolyte cathode and anode form an electrolytic cell. The voltages produced will influence the ohmmeter. The meter injects a current then measuring a voltage that calculates the resistance.

To measure the resistance, measure the voltage and current while operating. Apply Ohm’s Law.

The resistance is dependent on the evolution of the gases produced.